# org.hibernate.MappingException throwing by program

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

There are many solutions are present in Stack Overflow but none of them helps me. The problem is I have a table and corresponding to that table I have a POJO class for Hibernate. Reverse Engineering is off in hbm.xml file. Scenario is like this:

For example:

Table A column (a,b,c,d)

Corresponding this table a POJO A with property a,b,c. I didn't map 'd' yet. Till here it's working fine. Now after some time I also want 'd' in my mapping class so I added 'd' with setters and getters but now when I am deploying my application it's throwing following exception.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [db.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: RewardCondition column: created (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at o
```

**For more info:** There is no foreign key associated with 'created' column and I am using annotations for mapping.

**Edit:** I added this code in my previously working POJO

```
@column(name="created")
private Date created;
public Date getCreated() {
    return created;
}

public void setCreated(Date created) {
    this.created = created;
}
```

Comment: Please show the code of your pojo

Comment: @Jens it's just property with setters and getters. I added edit in my question.

Comment: Looks like you have the column `created` twice in your pojo?

Comment: please post full code. With which entity its mapping is taking place?

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely because the getter "getCreated" is being mapped automatically, and you've placed the @Column annotation on the private member.  Move the column mapping to the getter, or remove it completely.

```
private Date created;

@Column(name="created")
public Date getCreated() {
    return created;
}

public void setCreated(Date created) {
    this.created = created;
}
```